# How can manage openfire connection on 2G network?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, openfire

I created messaging application like whatsApp and hike. Its working on 3G,4G and Wifi network. when user switch to 2G network my app connection is interrupted but whatsApp and hike working perfectly. I posting code where i manage app connection ::

```
#pragma mark - connect to the server

- (BOOL)connect {

if (!self.xmppStream) {
    [self setupStream];
}

NSString *jabberID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:kUserName];
if (![self.xmppStream isDisconnected]) {
    return YES;
}

if (jabberID == nil || kXMPPPassword == nil) {

    return NO;
}
[self.xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:jabberID]];

[self.xmppStream setHostName:kXMPPHost];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![self.xmppStream connectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:&error])
{
    //        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Can't connect to server %@", [error localizedDescription]]  delegate:nil  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    //        [alertView show];

    NSLog(@"errorerrorerrorerrorerrorerror :- %@", error);
    return NO;
}
return YES;}

 - (void)connectThenSignIn {
    if ([_xmppStream isConnecting]) {   // Connection error, connection is being established
    return ;
}
if ([_xmppStream isDisconnected]) {     // If disconnected, a server connection is established
    [self connect];
    _goToRegisterAfterConnected = NO;
} else if ([_xmppStream isConnected]) {   
    [self doSignIn];
} }
```

Please suggest me best way to manage openfire connection on every network (2G, 3G, 4G and wifi).

Answer (score 1):

Those applications are probably using push notifications to receive updates while on unreliable IP networks (like 2G). This allows them to appear online without maintaining a constant connection to a server.

This is difficult to accomplish with XMPP -- the protocol was written with the assumption that users only need to be reachable while they are connected to the server. Some XEP extensions have added partial workarounds, but the protocol as a whole is poorly suited to mobile clients. ([This has been a well-known limitation since at least 2014.](https://op-co.de/blog/posts/mobile_xmpp_in_2014/)) You may want to consider alternatives.